# How to observe Bool properties with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have two Bool properties in my VC.swift:

```
var isRecording = false
var isPlaying = false
```

In the viewDidLoad() method I have such code:

```
let observable = Observable.combineLatest(self.rx_observe(Bool.self, "isRecording"), self.rx_observe(Bool.self, "isPlaying")) { (val1, val2) -> Void in
        if(val1 == false && val2 == false){
            self.recordButton.enabled = true
            self.playButton.enabled = true
            self.recordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "record"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else if(val1 == true && val2 == false){
            self.recordButton.enabled = true
            self.recordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "stop"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.playButton.enabled = false
        } else if(val1 == false && val2 == true){
            self.recordButton.enabled = false
            self.playButton.enabled = true
            self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "stop"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.recordButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "record"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    addSubscription(observable.subscribe())
```

The function addSubscription(:_) adds subscription to DisposableBag. 
The problem is that the code in the closure works only once. It does not work when properties "isRecording" and "isPlaying" change. What should I do if I want this code to be performed after I have these bool properties changed?

Comment: Change that properties when status is changed, I means playing or recording will finished and start again. You implemented it in viewdidload so it's called only once when it loads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `Bool` and `rx_observe`.  Instead, use a `Subject` such as `Variable<Bool>`.

```
let isRecording = Variable(false)
let isPlaying = Variable(false)

let observable = Observable.combineLatest(isRecording.asObservable(), isPlaying.asObservable()) { (val1, val2) -> Void in
    //...
```

However, to answer your question as to why it doesn't work with `rx_observe`, it's because `rx_observe` relies on the property being KVO compliant.  If you used the `dynamic` keyword in front of your property definitions, it would have worked: `dynamic var isRecording = false`.  However, you should really be using a `Subject` such as `Variable`.  Check out the playground page dealing with `Subject`s in the `RxSwift` repo.  It gives an example of each type.

Comment: Thank u very much. It works. But I used this: let observable = Observable.combineLatest(isRecording.asObservable(), isPlaying.asObservable()) { (val1, val2) -> Void in
    //...

Comment: Ah thanks for the catch.  I've updated the answer.  I also added an explanation as to why it wasn't working for you before.

Answer (score 3):

With latest RxSwift 5.0+ you can use `BehaviorRelay`

```
let isLoading = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
```

And you can observe it's value as below:

```
isLoading.asObservable().subscribe { status in
                print(status)
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```